# Switching on MySQL query profiler for a website?

Tags: mysql, php, optimization

I want to "swtich" on the sql query profiler for my php/mysql site and leave it ru nnig for a while.

The idea is to capture usage details over a day and then analayze the queries and work out which ones need tweaking...

I did this from the command prompt (mysql):

```
mysql> show profiles;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set profiling=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

// loaded the website

mysql> show profiles;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

But no results. How do i turn it on for the website?

Comment: @kedare - this is a problem for me - there has to be a better way - i've got sql queries all across my system,  - how can i centralize those!!

Answer (score 0):

The profiling is only enabled for the current session, you have to execute the queries by hand on the same session.

Comment: @all - how can i turn it "on" for the entire website? different users will have different sessions and i want to profile ALL of that naturally!

Comment: @Frank I don't think that is possible. You need to log your queries, come up with some you want to tweak (e.g. the slowest and the most common), then run them manually in a session with profiling enabled.

Comment: @sciurus - any thoughts on how i can setup my php applicaito n whichis running fine to now log these queries?

Comment: Make you php application run the SET PROFILING=1; before any query, and SET PROFILING=0; after, then dumping your queries profiles with SHOW PROFILES then SHOW PROFILE ALL FOR QUERY X for each query.

Answer (score 0):

The command SHOW PROFILES added in MySQL Community Server since 5.0.37 version. Check your version of the MySQL Server.